# How to show the content in a .nfo file on the web?

Tags: php, html, web, viewer

I need to find out some plugin or code to be able to show the content of a .nfo file on a webpage (html or php) . The plan is to make many web pages with one .nfo file on each, and I am not sure if this is workable with some code or if there is a script/portal/cms that has this ability?

I have google'd for 2 days now, but all I can find is windows viewers etc...and nothing web based. Is there anyone here that can help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and response if it's working (or not):

> echo readfile("yourfile.nfo");

If you have lines try this

```
$handle = fopen("yourfile.nfo", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        echo $line."<br>";
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

Don't forget the tags ;)

Comment: hi Baldoius, I tried what you said but it just got me that line 'written' on the web page (see screenshot) http://prntscr.com/66o3ln

Comment: You forgot the begin and end tags. This would be correct:  `<?php echo readfile("yourfile.nfo"); ?>`

Comment: sorry my bad :( ...it did show a output now, but it wasnt pretty and organized as I had hoped for, and how it is in the file. I will try and tweak it a little, with maybe some ASCII stuff in the header. http://prntscr.com/66o8jn . But thanks for the help :)

Comment: output http://prntscr.com/66ocuy ...and code http://prntscr.com/66od5r . I think I am a newbie here :(

Comment: You forgot the begin and end tags  again. See the second comment

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks so much for your help :) Now I just need to re-check the .nfo file, cause it was not like I was hoping for hehe. But it worked perfectly..thank you . http://www.brueland.net/nfo/index.php